# Send array from a javascript file to index.js in Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, arrays, express

I've been having trouble sending an array (or JSON object would work too) from script.js (code for my html) to index.js (my express server file).

I've researched it and it either has to do with sending the variable to an HTML file and then to another javascript file off of it (which can't be applied to this) or using localStorage (which also cannot be used inside of node) and also I've tried making a POST request and sending it that way but I couldn't figure out how to do it (making the contents of the request itself).

Please help! (sorry if I'm making a dumb question but I'm pretty inexperienced)

Code (index.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = module.exports = express();
var engines = require('consolidate');
var fs = require('fs');
app.engine('php', engines.mustache);
app.set('view engine', 'php');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views/'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')));
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.render('index.php');
});

if (!module.parent) {
  app.listen(3000);
  console.log('Express started on port 3000');
}
function submitColors(e) {
    fs.writeFile("./colors.txt", JSON.encode(e), (err) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log("Successfully sent JSON to colors.txt (Array: " + e + " and JSON " + JSON.encode(e));
        }
    });
}
app.get('/colors', function(req, res) {
  submitColors(cArray);
  res.render('index.php');
  res.send('Colors maybe sent successfully?');
});
```

Code (frontend index.php (no php code, i just tried php and havent turned it back):

```
<div id="buttons-div">
        <button id="yellow-button" onclick="changeColor('yellow')"></button>
        <button id="red-button" onclick="changeColor('red')"></button>
        <button id="blue-button" onclick="changeColor('blue')"></button>
        <button id="white-button" onclick="changeColor('white')"></button>
        <button id="green-button" onclick="changeColor('green')"></button>
        <form method="POST" action="colors">    
            <input id="submit" type="submit"></input>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Code (script.js):

```
function changeColor(e) {
    if(e == "red") {
        console.log('red');
        addColor('red');
    }
    else if (e == "blue") {
        console.log('blue');
        addColor('blue');
    }
    else if (e == "green") {
        console.log('green');
        addColor('green');
    }
    else if (e == "yellow") {
        console.log('yellow');
        addColor('yellow');
    }
    else if (e == "white") {
        console.log('white');
        addColor('white');
    }
}
function isInArray(array, string) {
    if(array.indexOf(string.toString()) >= 0) {
        console.log(array.indexOf(string.toString()) + " true and is inside");
        return true;
    }
    else if (array.indexOf(string.toString()) < 0){
        console.log(array.indexOf(string.toString()) + " false and is not inside");
        return false;
    }
}

var cArray = [];
function addColor(c) {
    if(isInArray(cArray, c) == true) {
        var a = cArray.indexOf(c.toString());
        delete cArray[a];
        console.log('deleted ' + c + ' from the list');
        return true;
    }
    else {
        cArray.push(c.toString());
        console.log('added color ' + c + ' to the list');
    }
    
}
```

I need to transfer my array (cArray) from the script file for coding the HTML page to the express index.js.

Comment: Where is the frontend code?

Comment: Why not export from script js and require it in index js? Does it work that way?

Comment: @KostasMinaidis The frontend code shouldn't matter, its just buttons adding to an array and a submit button that does nothing

Comment: @riskylast I'm not sure, when I tried to do that it showed up as require is not defined or something. Also, it needs to be updated whenever I click submit (which now that I think about it, would be a good idea to add to the question), so does require update everytime the variable/array is updated? Also why does it have that error

Comment: @Gage "The frontend code shouldn't matter, its just buttons adding to an array and a submit button that does nothing" < Since you are trying to send code from the frontend (html), the code does matter. Also, since the submit button does nothing, how is anything supposed to reach the backend?

Comment: @ggorlen Ok I will paste all that into the code but I still don't see how it matters since I'm not experiencing an error or anything, I'm just asking for a recommendation on how to do something.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis because I'm looking for how do it? (sorry if I sound aggressive) If you read, I'm looking for recommendations on how to do something, not experiencing an error or anything of that sorts.

Comment: @Gage I see. No worries, I misinterpreted the question. I've pasted a simple setup for sending an Array from the frontend to the backend. Let me know if this covers your case.

Comment: @KostasMinaidis Thanks! I ended up using a different solution that I hadn't thought of with socket.io but your solution is actually what I asked for so I marked it as the answer and upvoted it.

Comment: @Gage Keep in mind that WebSockets (socket.io) is a two-way communication between client and server, where the server can also initiate requests towards the client. Depending on the case, you'll either need an Ajax request (client initiates requests, server responds), WebSockets (client+server initiate requests and also respond) or Server-Sent Events (server initiates requests)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a very basic setup to send an Array from the client (index.html) to an Express server (server.js) in the form of JSON.

index.html:

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- We will use a simple form to submit the Array, but any JS function can do the fetch() request autonomously -->
        <form>
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
        <script>
        // The Array that will be send to the server:
        const arrayDestinedForServer = [ "A", 42, false ]; // This would be your cArray

        const form = document.querySelector("form");

        // Handle the form's submit event (when the button Submit gets clicked)
        form.addEventListener("submit", e =>{
            // Prevent the default HTML form submission behavior:
            e.preventDefault();

            // Send the Array as a stringified JSON to the server via an Ajax request using the Fetch API:
            fetch("http://localhost:3000/colors", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                body: JSON.stringify(arrayDestinedForServer)
            })
            .then( res => res.json() ) // <= Handle JSON response from server
            .then( data => console.log(data) )
            .catch( error => console.error(error) );
        })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

server.js:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
app.use( require("express").json() ); // <== Make sure we can handle JSON data from the client

// Handle POST request from client:
app.post("/colors", (req,res)=>{
    console.log( req.body ); // <== Receives: [ 'A', 42, false ]
    res.status(200).json({ received: req.body }); // Send back a confirmation JSON response
});

app.listen( 3000, ()=>{
    console.log("Server listening on http://localhost:3000");
});
```

Let me know if this helps.